# I want to create my own tables in it and work on them

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle SQL developer on my personal computer.

I want to create my own tables in it and work on them.

But, when I try to make the basic connection, it gives an error below
i want to practice but  on sql developer but there is no connection what to do help needed

Comment: You need an Oracle database server somewhere.

Comment: test failed no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Comment: But i dont want to connect to server because i have to practice my course

Comment: You want screenshot

Comment: please help me to connect

Comment: @RazaKhan If you dont have an Oracle Database Server exactly what are your practicicing. You have to query something?

Comment: so where i get the database give me  link

Comment: You can't work on a DB server if you don't have a DB server...

Comment: You: I need help cooking
Me: Turn your oven/stove on.
You: I just want to practice. I dont want to turn on oven/stove
Me: Practice what
You: Cooking

Comment: i have 11g but still not connecting or i dont know the setup how to make connection to the database

Comment: so can you guyz tell me how to connect with llg database oracle

Comment: It isn't entirely clear if you do actually have a DB you can try to connect to. You've buried an error message in a comment - edit that into the question and show the connection settings you're trying to test when you see that. We can't see what you are doing. That error might even be slightly interesting, but I think it means you're trying to use the wrong connection type (thick via TNS, instead of thin via basic).

Comment: Let's start with something easier... Can you start SQLPlus? (If you don't know what that means: open a "command" window and type sqlplus; report back what happens when you do that.) By the way, Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

You have SQL Developer, but you probably don't have a database. You have a few options of how to proceed next.

Create your own database - after you download and install Oracle Database or Oracle XE.

Find someone else's database you can use.

Download a virtual image you can start that's already setup for Oracle Database.

We have a free VirtualBox appliance you can download and run in less than an hour. You can read about that [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/introducing-the-otn-developer-day-database-12c-virtualbox-image/).

[image]